# SQL code reading nvarchar variable length

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having trouble with a sequence of code that is not reading the `NVARCHAR` length of my variables (they are barcode strings). We have two different barcodes and the inventory system I have set up measures only the format of the original one (has 7 characters). The new barcode has 9 characters. I need to run a loop value through each barcode input, hence how I have set up this line of script.

I originally thought that a DATALENGTH or LEN function would suffice but it seems that it is only measuring the variable as an integer, not the 7 characters in the string. If anybody has any input of how to manipulate my code sequence or a function that will measure a variables nvarchar length, it would more than appreciated!

```
CASE WHEN @BarcodeID = LEN(7) 

THEN UPPER(LEFT(@BarcodeID,2))+CONVERT(nvarchar,RIGHT(@BarcodeID,5)+@LoopValue-1) 
ELSE UPPER(LEFT(@BarcodeID,3))+CONVERT(nvarchar,RIGHT(@BarcodeID,6)+@LoopValue-1) END
```

Once again, the `LEN(7)` function in the beginning seems to be my issue.

Comment: Is there a question hiding here?

Comment: Yes I edited the original posting, it was my first time ever posting on here. Usually get a lot of great input for when I need help with writing codes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you're trying to do is actually

```
CASE WHEN LEN(@BarcodeID) = 7
```

By using `@BarcodeID = LEN(7)` you are basically testing to see if the `@BarcodeID` variable is equal to 1 because the `LEN()` function, ["Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) It is implicitly converting 7 to a one-character string.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much.